# Meteor input field array undefined

Tags: arrays, forms, meteor

I'm trying to make an input field array like this:

```
<input type='text' name='answers[]'>
```

When I trigger the form submit event in Meteor en try to get the value of the "answers[]" input fields, like so:

```
Template.pollModal.events
  'submit form': (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()

    console.log e.target.answers.value
```

I get an undefined error.

Anyone got an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: @RobinK why are you assigning input name an array ?try with out giving input  name as array,it may work for you

Comment: @Kyll Thanks, this solved my problem!

Comment: @NareshKumar Because there can be multiple answers.